# Database Design - Which design should I use? Two options

Tags: database-design, postgresql

I'm designing a database schema using PostgreSQL. I have some doubts about which design should I use.

The table `tdir_details_uris_text` will have many millions of registers, each key `domain`, `uri`, `id_language` will have about 10/20 registers.

Which design should perform well? The 3 tables design or the 2 tables design?

Best Regards,

PS: Sorry for my poor English.

[image]

[image]

---

Update: Just to add an INSERT INTO example

```
insert into tdir_details_uris_text (domain, uri, id_language, id_categorie, id_data, id_ordinal, n_text) values ('motors.shop.ebay.com', 'http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/2009-FORD-MUSTANG-GT-BLACK-BEAUTY-16K-MILES-WOW-/230580626087?pt=US_Cars_Trucks&hash=item35afad22a7', 'en', '23', 'title_webpage', '1', '2009 Ford Mustang GT');
insert into tdir_details_uris_text (domain, uri, id_language, id_categorie, id_data, id_ordinal, n_text) values ('motors.shop.ebay.com', 'http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/2009-FORD-MUSTANG-GT-BLACK-BEAUTY-16K-MILES-WOW-/230580626087?pt=US_Cars_Trucks&hash=item35afad22a7', 'en', '23', 'highlights', '1', 'No Accidents / Damage Reported to CARFAX');
insert into tdir_details_uris_text (domain, uri, id_language, id_categorie, id_data, id_ordinal, n_text) values ('motors.shop.ebay.com', 'http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/2009-FORD-MUSTANG-GT-BLACK-BEAUTY-16K-MILES-WOW-/230580626087?pt=US_Cars_Trucks&hash=item35afad22a7', 'en', '23', 'highlights', '2', 'No Airbag Deployment Reported to CARFAX');
insert into tdir_details_uris_text (domain, uri, id_language, id_categorie, id_data, id_ordinal, n_text) values ('motors.shop.ebay.com', 'http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/2009-FORD-MUSTANG-GT-BLACK-BEAUTY-16K-MILES-WOW-/230580626087?pt=US_Cars_Trucks&hash=item35afad22a7', 'en', '23', 'highlights', '3', 'Vehicle Qualifies for the CARFAX Buyback Guarantee');
insert into tdir_details_uris_text (domain, uri, id_language, id_categorie, id_data, id_ordinal, n_text) values ('motors.shop.ebay.com', 'http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/2009-FORD-MUSTANG-GT-BLACK-BEAUTY-16K-MILES-WOW-/230580626087?pt=US_Cars_Trucks&hash=item35afad22a7', 'en', '23', 'highlights', '4', 'No Structural/Frame Damage Reported to CARFAX');
insert into tdir_details_uris_text (domain, uri, id_language, id_categorie, id_data, id_ordinal, n_text) values ('motors.shop.ebay.com', 'http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/2009-FORD-MUSTANG-GT-BLACK-BEAUTY-16K-MILES-WOW-/230580626087?pt=US_Cars_Trucks&hash=item35afad22a7', 'en', '23', 'highlights', '5', 'No Manufacturer Recalls Reported to CARFAX');
insert into tdir_details_uris_text (domain, uri, id_language, id_categorie, id_data, id_ordinal, n_text) values ('motors.shop.ebay.com', 'http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/2009-FORD-MUSTANG-GT-BLACK-BEAUTY-16K-MILES-WOW-/230580626087?pt=US_Cars_Trucks&hash=item35afad22a7', 'en', '23', 'highlights', '6', 'No Indication of an Odometer Rollback');
```

Comment: The real question is: Which design fits the Model *and* Relation Algebra better? Always start there.

Comment: Is there a reason domain/url/id_language is in both tdir_detauls_uris_text and tdir_uris_text? That seems to be a flaw in the model, just at a glance. At any rate, I'm not sure of the real "model" that is trying to be presented. Is it a one-many or a many-many, etc? Make sure to capture that requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "tdirs_uris_text" table in option 1 has no purpose that I can see (if you only have the two tables in your entire design).  The question to ask is whether the primary key in "tdirs_uris_text" will ever be used multiple times on a different table (as a foreign key).  Specifically, would there ever be a case where the "details" table has the "uris" foreign key appear multiple times?  If so option 1 is better otherwise option 2 is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a many-to-many relationship, which would require a three table design.

But I don't think it's the design you show.  I don't see the correct primary key relationship.

Table A would have ID_A as primary key.

Table B would have ID_B as primary key.

The JOIN Table AB would have primary key ID_A, ID_B; each one would be a foreign key into Table A and B, respectively.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have updated with an INSERT INTO example. In which table is the primary key not correct? Best Regards,